# The number of esquares of idempotents in the rank 2 $\mathcal{D}$-class of $M_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, semigroups, idempotents

Here's a variation of a question I was given during a research internship.

### Some Definitions:

**Definition 1:** Let $S$ be a semigroup. For any $a, b\in S$, define *Green's $\mathcal{L}$-relation* by $a\mathcal{L}b$ if and only if $S^1a=S^1b$ and define *Green's $\mathcal{R}$-relation* by $a\mathcal{R}b$ if and only if $aS^1=bS^1$, where $S^1$ is $S$ with a one adjoined if necessary. Then *Green's $\mathcal{D}$-relation* is given by $a\mathcal{D}b$ if and only if $a(\mathcal{L}\circ\mathcal{R})b$ (which is equivalent to $a(\mathcal{R}\circ\mathcal{L})b$); that is, there exists a $c\in S$ such that $a\mathcal{L}c\mathcal{R}b$

**Definition 2:** The *rank* of a matrix is the number of linearly independent columns it has.

### The Question:

> Let $S=M_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$. Let $D^{(n)}_2$ be the matrices in the rank $2$ $\mathcal{D}$-class of $S$. Find
>
> $$N_n=\left\lvert\left\{\left.\begin{array}
> \, e & \mathcal{L} & f \\
> \mathcal{R} & \, & \mathcal{R} \\
> h & \mathcal{L} & g
> \end{array}\right\vert e, f, g, h\in E\left(D^{(n)}_2\right)\right\}\right\rvert;$$ that is, find $N_n$,  the number of quadruples $(e, f, g,h)\in E\left(D_2^{(n)}\right)^4$ such that $e\mathcal{L}f\mathcal{R}g\mathcal{L}h\mathcal{R}e$.

Here $E(T)$ is the set of idempotents of the semigroup $T$.

### Background:

I did most of the cases when $n=4$ and $n=6$ using the programming language [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org). For the $6\times 6$ case, I sorted matrices of the $D^{(6)}_2$ into certain types (that I can't produce from memory as my notes are missing) then had GAP do an iterated procedure to find $N_6$.

Comment: What do you call "the -class of $S$"? The semigroup $S$ has several $\cal D$-classes.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I'm not sure. The $\mathcal{D}$-class of matrices of rank $2$ perhaps.

Comment: I think the question could be better formulated. First of all, someone may have (hopefully wrong) an impression that you were given a question during your internship and now you're soliciting help on this site. If you have something different in mind, please make it more clear. Also, are you interested in trying larger $n$ with GAP, or this is not a question about GAP? How to read the formula for $N_n$? Why there are empty spaces there? Also, $e$ is not used there. Is there a name for $N_n$?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov The internship ended a couple of years ago. This is not a question about​ GAP. The formula for $N_n$ is what I'm after. What empty spaces? I have made $e$ clearer. There's no name for $N_n$ I am aware of.

Comment: I'm looking for the number of quadruples $(e, f, g,h)\in E\left(D_2^{(n)}\right)^4$ such that $e\mathcal{L}f\mathcal{R}g\mathcal{L}h\mathcal{R}e$.

Comment: @Shaun Now $e$ became visible - there was a hole on its place before, so thanks for fixing this and clarification. Also found https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.1242.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/0808.1827.pdf which clarified the notation for me.

Comment: @Shaun do you still have values of $N_n$ for $n=4$ and $6$?

Comment: I did; well, I got close at least. My notes have gone missing since then and my laptop (with all the GAP stuff on) broke.

Comment: Could you give us the motivation for this question? As it is stated, it looks rather artificial to me, but I suppose there is some interest in computing $N_n$.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer to the question posed, but is also too long to fit into a comment. I believe that the following lines of GAP code compute the value of $N_4$, $N_5$, $N_6$, and $N_7$. This uses the [Semigroups](https://gap-packages.github.io/Semigroups/) and [Digraphs](https://gap-packages.github.io/Digraphs/) packages for GAP:

```
S := GLM(4, 2); # The monoid of 4x4 matrices over the field with 2 elements
S := GLM(5, 2);
S := GLM(6, 2);
# Find the first (and only) D-class with row/column rank equal to 2.
D := First(DClasses(S), x -> RowRank(Representative(x)) = 2); 

# The following function creates a bipartite graph from the principal
# factor of D, such that there is an edge from vertex i to vertex j if
# there is an idempotent in the intersection of RClasses(D)[i] and
# LClasses(D)[j], and then counts the number of e-squares using that graph. 
NrESquares := function(D)
  local gr, out, m, count, com, i, j;
  gr := RZMSDigraph(PrincipalFactor(D));
  out := OutNeighbors(gr);
  m := NrRClasses(D);
  count := 0;
  for i in [1 .. m - 1] do 
    for j in [i + 1 .. m] do 
      com := Intersection(out[i], out[j]);
      if Size(com) >= 2 then
        count := count + Binomial(Size(com), 2);
      fi;
    od;
    Print("at ", i, " of ", m, ", found ", count, " so far\n");
  od;
  return count;
end;
```

According to which $N_4 = 13020$, $N_5 = 4010160$, $N_6 = 1069306560$, and $N_7 = 275635858176$. On my laptop, finding $N_4$ took about 1 second, $N_5$ about 10 seconds, $N_6$ about 3 minutes, and $N_7$ about an hour.

The majority of the computation is finding the `PrincipalFactor`, which uses a method which works for any (finite) semigroup in GAP. A more specialist method for counting E-squares might be able to do it more quickly.

Comment: No OEIS sequence with $\dots, 13020,4010160, \dots$ in it.

Comment: Yup I noticed that too