# Solved Exercises in GAP.

Tags: reference-request, gap

*If this is too broad a question, I'm sorry.*

I'm looking for some solved exercises in [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) to get some practise using it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Answers like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2223868/104041) would be great.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/CGT/howtogap.pdf

Comment: I have. You've just reminded me that it's on my laptop. Thank you, @ahulpke.

Comment: See also GAP Software Carpentry lesson at http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/ and various tips from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/104195/

Comment: P.S. If you will be looking for these links again, just go the GAP website -> Documentation -> Learning GAP: http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Learning/learning.html

Comment: Shall we close this question as answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/104195/ then?