# Brauer Character in GAP.

Tags: group-theory, characters, gap

What is command to obtain  Brauer Character in GAP? In magma, it is like

```
> G := Sym(5);
> I := AbsolutelyIrreducibleModules(G, GF(3));
> [BrauerCharacter(i): i in I];
[
    ( 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ),
    ( 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0 ),
    ( 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0 ),
    ( 4, -2, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0 ),
    ( 6, 0, -2, 0, 0, 1, 0 )
]
```

Please tell me the same for GAP.

Thanks.

Comment: @Shaun thanks for edit and answer ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, as in the quote from the GAP manual given by @Shaun, trying to do this immediately in GAP fails:

```
gap> G:=SymmetricGroup(5);
Sym( [ 1 .. 5 ] )
gap> t:=CharacterTable(G);
CharacterTable( Sym( [ 1 .. 5 ] ) )
gap> t mod 3;
fail
```

The GAP Character Table Library is provided by the [CTblLib package](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Thomas.Breuer/ctbllib/) (in most installations, it is loaded by default, otherwise one should load it first with `LoadPackage("ctbllib");`. Then you can retrieve the character table from the library. In your example, do the following:

```
gap> t:=CharacterTable("S5") mod 3;
BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 )
gap> Irr(t);
[ Character( BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 ), [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ), 
  Character( BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 ), [ 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 ] ), 
  Character( BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 ), [ 6, -2, 1, 0, 0 ] ), 
  Character( BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 ), [ 4, 0, -1, 2, 0 ] ), 
  Character( BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 ), [ 4, 0, -1, -2, 0 ] ) ]
```

See `?AllCharacterTableNames` in GAP to search in identifiers of library tables. It could narrow the search if you are not sure which identifier to use, For example,

```
gap> AllCharacterTableNames(Size,120);
[ "2.A5", "2.A6M2", "2.Alt(5)", "2xA5", "A5.2", "A6.2_1M3", "D120", "L2(25)M3", "Sym(5)" ]
gap> AllCharacterTableNames(Size,7920,IsSimple,true);
[ "HSM9", "M11", "M12M2", "ONM11" ]
```

Comment: Thanks ... I will try this way and will tell....

Comment: Yes sir it is fine and working for me ... you explained exactly that I need... thank you very much ...

Comment: Sir can i ask one more question? If i want to learn about GAP from where to start ? I mean is there elementary level book of  GAP? Please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to start with the [GAP Software Carpentry lesson](http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/). It is aimed at beginners, and was taught at workshops, but should also be suitable for self-study. Then look also at my answer to the question [What is the best way to self-study GAP?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104195/what-is-the-best-way-to-self-study-gap).

Comment: Thanks ....................

Comment: Sir it does not work for $SL(2,5)$...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051924/loadpackagectbllib-is-not-working-for-sl2-5 ...Please check...Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> Currently GAP does not provide special functionality for computing Brauer character tables, but there is an interface to the MOC system (see [HJLP]), and the GAP Character Table Library contains many known Brauer character tables.

Found [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap71.html).

See "71.3-1 CharacterTable" onwards *ibid.* for the capabilities.

Comment: If want to learn about GAP from where to start ? I mean is there elementary level book of GAP? Please suggest me. Thanks

Comment: @neelkanth Simply search online for the GAP tutorial and the GAP manual. They're free PDFs with all the information you'll ever need.

Comment: There's also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2272232/104041), @neelkanth :)

Comment: @ Shaun     Thank you very much ...

Comment: please look at my problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051924/loadpackagectbllib-is-not-working-for-sl2-5