# To find Brauer Character for the special linear group SL(2,5) in GAP.

Tags: group-theory, gap

[As suggest by Alexander Konovalov](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3049857/104041) I load LoadPackage("ctbllib") and them worked for  symmetric group $S5$. It worked for me as

```
gap> t:=CharacterTable("S5") mod 3;
BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 )
gap> Irr(t);
[ Character( BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 ), [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ), 
  Character( BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 ), [ 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 ] ), 
  Character( BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 ), [ 6, -2, 1, 0, 0 ] ), 
  Character( BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 ), [ 4, 0, -1, 2, 0 ] ), 
  Character( BrauerTable( "A5.2", 3 ), [ 4, 0, -1, -2, 0 ] ) ]
```

But i tried same for Special linear group $SL(2,5)$, it does not works

gap> LoadPackage("ctbllib");

true

gap> m:=SL(2,5);

SL(2,5)

gap> t:=CharacterTable("m") mod 2;

fail

gap>

Where is problem. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The package *did* load. It returned `true`.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for edit...

Comment: @Shaun But not working to find Brauer Character...

Comment: Like group $S5$...

Comment: I don't know how to fix that, @neelkanth; I'm just saying that the problem doesn't seem to be with the package loading, as the title suggests.

Comment: ok then i change the title....

Comment: `m:=SL(2,5);` creates a variable `m` which contains a group. `"m"` is a string which contains a character `m`. It has no connection to the *variable* `m`. Incidentally, `"M"` and `"m"` are both identifiers for the character table of the monster simple group, which then is retrieved from the library by `CharacterTable("m")`, but it has no known character table mod 2, so `fail` is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up the (string) names of groups in the library and variables you choose to assign a group to. The group `"M"` in the libary is the monster simple group, and for it the Brauer table is not known.

The ATLAS name of $SL(2,5)$ is `2.L2(5)`, indeed we can get the table for it as

```
gap> t:=CharacterTable("2.L2(5)") mod 3;
BrauerTable( "2.A5", 3 )
```

Note that all of this is about pre-computed Brauer tables from the character table library. If you wanted to compute the Brauer table for an arbitrary finite group, you would have to find all irreducible modules (e.g. by splitting up the regular module), and then lift the Brauer character values appropriately (there currently is no pre-defined function which does so automatically).

Comment: Ok thanks sir.... i will try this way and will tell you .....

Comment: Yes Sir now it is working....thanks...

Comment: But How i will know in future about The ATLAS name of any other group....

Comment: @neelkanth If you are working with simple groups and their relatives, you might want to read through the preface of the ATLAS, as these names have become kind of standard. If you require the Brauer tables for other groups (and need to compute from scratch) I recommend the textbook by Lux and Pahlings published by Cambridge U.P. which contains GAP examples.

Comment: @ahulpkr thanks sir I will purchase this book ...

Comment: Sir I got a book with name “ Representation of groups ... a computational approach”  ...is it the same book ???

Comment: You can also take a look at the online version of the ATLAS here: http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/